# Brewed Beer in Pune

Tags: breweries

Does anybody know the best place for brewed beer in Pune, Maharashtra, India?

I have visited a few breweries in Mumbai recently, and I became a fan of the brewed beer, the flavours they offered there, mostly of the Belgian Ale.

I would like to know if there is any similarly good brewery in Pune? I would like to visit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is a very late answer I have found a good site that labels 3 good brewery's in [Pune](http://thelabel.in/lifestyle/food-drink/punes-3-best-breweries-for-seasonal-local-flavours-beers)

- The 1st Brewhouse
- TJ’s Brew Works
- Flambos

Comment: Nice find, even if late.

Comment: Thanks and Nice find Jamie, even later Acknowledgement by me, sorry for that. Sad news i don't drink anymore. Maybe a help for other people living in Pune.

Answer (score 0):

I would also add another place to the list. 
(In order I prefer to visit)

- The 1st Brewhouse
- Effingut (Most of the time they have 8 varieties on tap)
- TJ's Brew works (I dont find them that impressive)
- Flambos